# DevExpress ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged in asp.net mvc

Tags: devexpress

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ComboBox()
{

List<ComboBoxClass> Products = new List<ComboBoxClass>();
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Masa" });
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Sandalye" });
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Bilgisayar" });
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Laptop" });
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Kulaklık" });
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Bardak" });
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Kalem" });
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Seramik" });
Products.Add(new ComboBoxClass { ProductName = "Telefon" });

ViewData["Products"] = Products;

return View(Products);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(
settings =>
{
settings.Name = "BenimComboBox";
settings.Width = 180;
settings.Properties.ValueField = "ProductName";
settings.SelectedIndex = -1;
settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;
settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
settings.Properties.TextField = "ProductName";
settings.Properties.ValueField = "ProductName";
}
).BindList(ViewData["Products"]).GetHtml()
```

Class

```
public class ComboBoxClass
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have products.I list all products on ComboBox.How can ı pass my SelectedIndexChanged value to ActionResult ?

I want to see selected value below " string SelectedItem "

```
public ActionResult SelectedItemHere(string SelectedItem)
{
// Processes..
return View();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add below code to your Combobox,

```
settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "SelectedId";
```

After that

Javascript Code in your layout

```
function SelectedId() {
var data= {
SelectedItem: BenimComboBox.GetValue(),
};

$.ajax({
url: "/YOUR CONTROLLER/YOUR ACTİONRESULT",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

And Last,

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SelectedItemHere(string SelectedItem)
{
// Processes..
return View();
}
```

Comment: Workes perfect except I had to do a small change. Posting it just in case some other user can not get the function running.
         settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s,e){ getData()}";

Answer (score 0):

Access DevExpress ComboBox Selected Index by client side

```js
function OnComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged(e, s) {
    //check seleted index 

    var selected_index = e.lastSuccessValue;
    alert(selected_index);
            
  }
```

```html
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cbsample"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
<ClientSideEvents  SelectedIndexChanged="OnComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged" />
  
  <Items>
         <dx:ListEditItem  Text="item name"    Value="0" />
         <dx:ListEditItem  Text="item name1"  Value="1" />
         <dx:ListEditItem  Text="item name2" Value="2"  />
  </Items>
  
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```